# Why not finish all the functions within Update() function in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

void Update() can perform the functions per 1 frame . So in script , e.x like 
`void OnTriggerEnter(){}` . why don't put it in update() function .I know there's some misunderstanding here  but I just can't explain it to myself .Besides , is that only `void Update()`  , `void Start(){}` that functio in unity  .Including some functions like `void OnTriggerEnter` can function as well in unity since it is built-in functions  .How about those functions that written by us like `public void SwitchAvatar()` .Can it function if it is not referred inside `void Update(){}` .I know the questions above may sound stupid , but dunno why I can't tell the answers  .All of your help is greatly appreciated . Thanks !

Comment: Well depends on you where you want your code to be executed .. if you want it every few then yes put it in `Update` .. if you want it only in the first frame of a trigger collision put it in `OnTriggerEnter` ... A bit unclear where you are going with this question..

Comment: any diff b\w them .any example provided any result would be caused?

Comment: those simply are special methods the "actual engine" looks for.

Comment: Read the API documentation of Unity they describe pritty well which of these so called `messages` is called in which occasions... As said to your examples: `Start` is called only once before the first `Update`. `Update` is called every frame. `OnTriggerEnter` the first frame a trigger collides and well your custom method `SwitchAvatar` .. whenever you call it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, let's open pandoras box about magic methods in Unity.

First, there are two types of classes that you can inherit from, to access magic methods: `MonoBehaviour` and `ScriptableObject`. Both of them offer different things and the latter is mainly used to serialize data outside of scenes. Also, `ScriptableObject` has way less magic methods, compared to MonoBehaviour.

Second: A `MonoBehaviour` has a lifecycle. Where you are in this lifecycle determines what methods are called by the engine.

The following graphic shows you the whole lifecycle of a `MonoBehaviour`:
[image]
(Source: [Unity - Manual: Order of Executions for Event Functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html))

As you can see, the object gets instantiated and `Awake` is called. Before the first time `Update` is called, the engine calls the `Start` method. There is a difference between `Awake` and `Start`: `Awake` is comparable to a constructor. It is called without anything external being guaranteed to exist (like other components on your `GameObject`). When `Start` is called, all the other components on the object are initialized and can be accessed by a `GetComponent` call.

Now to `Update`, `FixedUpdate` and all the other events:
Unity has two separate cycles it iterates over. One for physics and one for everything else. Because calculating physics is expensive and needs precision, it is called in fixed, distinct time steps. You can actually set them in the project settings in the ["Time" tab](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TimeManager.html).
Now if you want to modify anything related to physics (like the velocity of a rigidbody), you should do that in `FixedUpdate`, because it runs in the same time step as the physics engine (PhysX or Box2D, depending on your usage of colliders).
Update on the other hand runs as often as possible. The current time distance between two Update calls can be observed by calling `Time.deltaTime`, which is the time that is passed between two `Update` calls. Note that `Time.fixedDeltaTime` is always the same, as it is the time between two physics calls.
The other event methods are called as responses to either the editor internal update loop, the rendering loop or the physics loop. Whenever an object collides in the physics calculation, `OnCollisionEnter` is called. Note that this can't happen out of `Update`, because, as we know, `Update` is not used to calculate physics.

---

Okay, a tl;dr:
`Start` and `Update` are not the only methods that exist in the `MonoBehaviour` lifecycle, there are plenty and each has its purpose. Physics are calculated in a different timescale as the `Update` method is called and thus cannot be part of `Update`.

---

And one thing to take away: You should really read the manual of the game engine you are using. There is plenty of stuff that you should know when you are writing code for a real time application and if you build onto an existing game engine, you should check the docs of that regularly. Especially the documentation of Unity is a very good read for both code and editor usage.

Comment: It seems misleading to word it as "`Update` runs as many times as possible" when the flow chart suggests that `Update` will never run more often than `FixedUpdate`. So really it seems like it only runs... "as many times as the whole game loop is able to run"? (edit: but still a great answer and a +1 from me.)

Comment: I didn't make the flow chart, so Unity themselves are to blame for it. However, `Update` still runs more often than `FixedUpdate`, except when a single frame takes longer than the phyiscs step. But you are right "as many times as the whole game loop is able to run" is probably a better wording.